# Terminal Set and Terminal Cost using Gekko Library

Tags: gekko, mpc, pendulum

I have a NMPC controller written in python using Gekko library for a nonlinear model of inverted pendulum mounted on the cart. I want to add terminal set and terminal cost using Gekko Library.

This is how I defined the objective function in code:

```
m.Obj(final*(x-xf)**2)
m.Obj(final*(xdot-xdotf)**2)
m.Obj(final*(q1-q1f)**2)
m.Obj(final*(q1dot-q1dotf)**2)
m.Obj(TF)
```

I don't know where and how to add terminal cost and terminal set?

Answer (score 0):

There are the [Inverted Pendulum Optimal Control](https://apmonitor.com/do/index.php/Main/InvertedPendulum) and the [Double Inverted Pendulum Optimal Control](https://apmonitor.com/do/index.php/Main/DoubleInvertedPendulum) example problems for reference. The terminal cost can be set by adding an additional weight (`w1`-`w4`) to each term to prioritize which one is met. In the example cases, all final conditions are met so the terminal cost is zero when (`w1=1`, `w2=1`, `w3=1`, `w4=1`). The solution may change when using different terminal weights.

```py
m.Minimize(final*w1*(x-xf)**2)
m.Minimize(final*w2*(xdot-xdotf)**2)
m.Minimize(final*w3*(q1-q1f)**2)
m.Minimize(final*w4*(q1dot-q1dotf)**2)
```

The terminal set is the set of final conditions that can be adjusted such as `xf`, `xdotf`, `q1f`, and `q1dotf`. Hard constraints can be used instead of the soft (objective-based) constraints above.

```py
m.Equation(final*(x-xf)==0)
m.Equation(final*(xdot-xdotf)==0)
m.Equation(final*(q1-q1f)==0)
m.Equation(final*(q1dot-q1dotf)==0)
```

However, this may lead to an infeasible solution if all constraints can't be met.